# Is it possible to achieve the following access levels

Tags: java, access-modifiers

Please let me know if these access levels are possible in java, if not what are the alternatives.

Question 1:

```
From same class:                yes
From subclass same package:     yes
From any class same package:    no
From subclass outside package:  no
From any class outside package: no
```

and
Question 2:

```
From same class:                yes
From subclass same package:     yes
From any class same package:    no
From subclass outside package:  yes
From any class outside package: no
```

None of the access modifiers(public/private/default/protected) provide the above set of control.

For eg:
I have a private member which is only accessible within the same class. How to give it an access control as stated in my first question?

Comment: Is this [tag:homework]? If so, it is advantageous to tag it as such.   Also: what do you think, and why?

Comment: not a homework. I have explained my question further.

Answer (score 2):

None of the java scopes do fit your *requirements*.

Comment: They work around it by just never referencing those variables anywhere else in the package.  You control the classes in the package, so there's not as much of a need to worry about accessibility constraints there.

Answer (score 1):

The access specifiers available in java doesn't match your requirements.

There is no distinction for

```
From subclass same package:      
From subclass outside package:
```

Comment: Hypothetically if one needs such levels of access. is there a workaround?

Comment: I am not sure @John... You want your class to be sub-classed and attributes to be accessible inside the package? Why package is so important factor here? its just a grouping of classes.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find them all here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: It doesn't provide what i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

This breakdown should help you decide the answer.

```
From same class:                 //private, default, protected, public
From subclass same package:      //default, protected, public
From any class same package:     //default, protected public
From subclass outside package:   //protected, public
From any class outside package:  //public
```

Comment: That's not correct, in java protected has a wider scope as default. Any class same package is true for protected.

Comment: @chaitanya10: i have clarified my question.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to achieve the 2 access level requirement you want.

There are only 4 access levels in Java, public, default, protected and private.  None of them matches what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The subclass in different package cannot be given separate access levels.

Only possible work around is to re-structure the packages :-(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible. but as mentioned above, it's not achieved by simply using the default available access modifiers. you need to add a *getter* to control the access to your attribute or method.

```
package house;

public class Father {
    private String secret = "I am your father";

    // for Q1 use default, for Q2 use protected
    protected String getSecret() {
        if(this.getClass().getName() != "house.Father") return secret;
        else return "some talk about the weather...";
    }
}
```

This getter allow the access by inheritance exclusively, and a direct access to the private attribute is always available. but the access by reference is denied.